# JBoss 6.2 EAP: Logging login attempts for management console

Tags: jboss6.x

How can JBoss EAP 6.2 be configured to log attempts to login to the Management Console?  Logging failed attempts would be sufficient.

We have enabled audit logging on our JBoss instance, and while that seems to log any actions taken once a user logs in to the Management Console, but not any successful or failed login attempts.